# MIPS MARS ASSEMBLY CODE operand is of incorrect type

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

```
 

.data
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter an integer: "
x: .double 2.0
tolerance: .double 1e-6

.text
main:
# Prompt user for initial value of x
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

# Read in user input
li $v0, 7
syscall

# Convert user input to double and store in x
mtc1 $v0, $f12
cvt.d.w $f0, $f12
sdc1 $f0, x

# Initialize counter and F(x) value
li $t0, 0
ldc1 $f12, x
add.d $f14, $f12, $f12
mul.d $f14, $f12, $f14
add.d $f14, $f14, 1

# Loop until F(x) is within tolerance
loop:
    # Calculate x{n+1}
    ldc1 $f12, x
    add.d $f13, $f12, $f12
    mul.d $f13, $f12, $f13
    mul.d $f13, $f13, $f12
    add.d $f13, $f13, -8
    mul.d $f13, $f13, $f12
    div.d $f12, $f14, $f13

    # Calculate F(x)
    ldc1 $f12, x
    add.d $f14, $f12, $f12
    mul.d $f14, $f12, $f14
    add.d $f14, $f14, 1

    # Print current x and F(x) values
    li $v0, 3
    ldc1 $f12, x
    syscall
    li $v0, 11
    li $a0, ','
    syscall
    li $v0, 3
    ldc1 $f14, $f14
    syscall
    li $v0, 11
    li $a0, '\n'
    syscall

    # Check if F(x) is within tolerance
    ldc1 $f12, x
    ldc1 $f14, tolerance
    c.lt.d $f12, $f14
    beq $0, $0, done

    # Increment counter and repeat loop
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    b loop

done:
    # Print root found
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, "Root found: "
    syscall
    li $v0, 3
    ldc1 $f12, x
    syscall

    # End program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

line 29 column 19: "1": operand is of incorrect type
line 46 column 23: "1": operand is of incorrect type
line 56 column 5: "ldc1": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: ldc$f2,-100($t2)
line 75 column 5: "la": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: la $t1,($t2)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? My goal is to write a MIPS program which will find a value of xn such that F(xn)=0, to a tolerance of 10-6 with the given formula +1 =  − (()/′()).

For example consider a continuous function F(x)=x3-4x2+1 with its derivative F’(x)=3x2-8x. Thus, by calculating successive values of x, the value of F(xn) will approach 0, and hence be a root of F.

I am fairly new to MIPS and I'm having trouble.

Comment: `add.d` requires 3 floating point registers to be named, it won't take a numeric argument.

Comment: `ldc1` requires a floating point register and a memory operand.  What would `ldc1 $f14, $f14` mean anyway?  If you're trying to move `$f14` into `$f12` for the syscall, use `mov.d`.

Comment: You need to put your string literal into the `.data` space, it won't do that for you.

Comment: The next problem you'll have is that you're using 64-bit double, but with odd register numbers, which are to be avoided when using doubles: MIPS pairs even/odd registers as they are only 32-bits wide individually.

Comment: ok for the add.d error. can a solution be to initialize another floating point register to 1 and then do add.d?

Comment: Yes, you can load 1.0 from memory, or convert a 1 as int to double 1.0.

Comment: ok I think I got it almost working now. Only issue is my program is not looping. I want it to look like this: 
Please enter an integer: 2
x=2.0, F(x)=-7.0
x=0.25, F(x)=0.765625
x=0.6724137931034483, F(x)=-0.5045358563286728 x=0.5469975054591968, F(x)=-0.033160000071302154 x=0.5374642805088174, F(x)=-2.1525861187732254E-4 x=0.5374015797596746, F(x)=-9.386846855363729E-9 x=0.5374015797596746 but I get this Please enter an integer: 2
7.0,7.0XRoot found: 7.0

Comment: Ok, find where it is finished with one iteration and put some code it to make it go back and run some code again.

Comment: I did with a b loop.